# Using PHP to send a flash video to be shown on a HTML page

Tags: php, html, flash, video, flashvars

I want to play a flash video on a webpage, but the source file (*.flv) is outside of webroot.

To be able to access this source file, I gave flashvars a php file reference. This php file will set the headers and return the correct flv file data. I expected this to work, but it is not working.

My response header shows a Content type value of : text/html, whereas if I try to play the video file directly the header is video/x-flv. What might be the problem and any ways to solve it would be great!

My HTML source

```
<object id=0 type="video/x-flv" data=123.swf width=640 height=360>
<param name="movie" value=123.swf />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="menu" value="true" />
<param name="autoplay" value="false" />
<param name="autoload" value="false" />
<param name="FlashVars" value="flv=media.php" />
</object>
```

My PHP data in media.php file -
    `<?php
    header("Content-Type: video/x-flv");
    readfile("videos/vid1.flv");

    ?>`

However, when I click the video to play, the response headers have a content-type of text/html. I guess, that is the root cause why the video is not playing.

Any help?

Comment: Try removing the tailing `?>` doubt it will work but it is worth a shot. In case there are trailing spaces or anything.

Comment: If you go to your media.php file directly, what do you see? Perhaps some sort of PHP error/warning is being displayed.

Comment: I was getting the following error - Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent. However, as mentioned by Jonan, i got rid of whitespaces and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there aren't any tabs/spaces in front of the `<?php` tag. This'll cause PHP to give an error when you do `header("Content-Type: video/x-flv");`, thus keeping the content type `text/html`.

**Edit**
It might help to end the script with `exit()`, to make sure nothing else is ouputted (a tab or space for example, after the trailing `?>`)